# Can't obtain token due to unauthorized_client error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, token, access-token, identityserver4

I'm composing a demo on how to obtain a token from IDS4 using Postman.

The request for password token is taken from [IDS4's page](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html?highlight=RequestTokenAsync#requesting-a-token-using-the-password-grant-type).

```
[HttpGet("token")]
public IActionResult GetToken([FromHeader] string user, [FromHeader] string pass)
{
  string tokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44300/connect/token";
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  Task<TokenResponse> tokenResponse = 
    client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
  {
    Address = tokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "client_secret",
    Scope = "MemberApi.full",

    UserName = user,
    Password = pass
  });
  TokenResponse toko = tokenResponse.Result;

  if (toko.IsError)
    return Ok(toko.Error);
  return Ok(toko.AccessToken;
}
```

The clients are set up as follows.

```
private static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients => new[]
{
  ...
  new Client
  {
    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("client_secret".Sha256()) },
    ClientName = "Client",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/security/credentials" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/index.html" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:44300" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
      "MemberApi",
      "MemberApi.full",
      "MemberApi.limited"
    }
  }
};
```

The API resources are set up as the following shows.

```
private static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis => new[]
{
  new ApiResource
  {
    Name = "MemberApi",
    DisplayName = "Members' API",
    ApiSecrets = {new Secret("MemberSecret".Sha256())},
    UserClaims = {JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.Email, JwtClaimTypes.Role},
    Scopes = {new Scope("MemberApi.full"), new Scope("MemberApi.limited")}
  }
};
```

As far I can tell I followed the suggestions in the docs. I've tried to compare with the examples, too. Despite that, I get stuck on the error saying *unauthorized_client*. What can I be missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The client request is not allowed in this flow:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit
```

Forget client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync. You don't need it and you can't use it. In the *implicit flow* only the user knows the password. It is out of reach for the client.

Assume IdentityServer runs on one domain: https://idp.mydomain.com and the client runs somewhere else: https://mvc.mydomain.com

When the user hits a secured page on the mvc client, the user is *routed to IdentityServer* where the user logs in. There the user enters the credentials and if succesful the user is returned to the client as a known identity.

Depending on the flow the client eventually ends up with at least an access token. This token is important because that allows the client to access the resource *on behalf of the user*. It is like an entry ticket.

Based on the access token the resource now knows WHO wants to access the resource. The access token has one claim that makes this distinction, the 'sub' claim. Without this claim the client has no access to the resource in this flow.

In your configuration the client is allowed to access the 'MemberApi' scopes, but it needs the user's consent before it actually can access the resource.

---

If you want to retrieve a token start with the easiest flow there is, the [client credentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#client-credentials) flow.

That's the flow where there is no user at all. The client (as in piece of software) can login using the clientid + secret. When configured properly this will result in an access token.

Now the client can access the resource without any user interaction. The identity token is not available as there is no user. The 'sub' claim is missing. The refresh token is not supported in this flow, it doesn't need it. The client can request a new token using the credentials.

---

If you want to know how the [refresh token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#refresh-tokens) works, in a [hybrid flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#hybrid) the user logs in and in addition (if scope=offline is configured) a refresh token is returned.

As an access token is only valid for a short time (depends on the expiration time) a new token must be acquired. For this the refresh token should be used. The refresh token allows the client to request a new access token without requiring user interaction (offline access).

The new access token is used until it expires and a new token must be requested. Until the refesh token itself expires, but that can be configured.

---

In the [implicit flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#implicit) there is no refresh token, but the access token does expire all the same. So you'll need another way to refresh the token. For that you can use something like a [silent token renew](https://damienbod.com/2017/06/02/implementing-a-silent-token-renew-in-angular-for-the-openid-connect-implicit-flow/) implementation.

For terminology please read the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html).

Please note the various flows. It all depends on the circumstances. Is there a user or not, is it a browser application, is there a front-channel, back-channel, is offline access required, can the client keep a secret? Things that need to be considered before choosing a flow.

When a flow is chosen, you need to configure the allowed grants for clients. A client using client credentials cannot access the resource if only an implicit grant type is allowed.

IdentityServer is mostly about configuring clients and resources. Take a look at the samples to see the different flows and how they are configured.

Comment: This was one kick-ass reply. I can't bounty you for two more days but I fully intend to. Great effort! That being said, I have a request for a few clarifications. (Right below here in a jiffy.)

Comment: I've made the client cred flow successfully so that's behind be. However, now, I'd like to get a better understanding of how my SPA will authenticate/authorize. If I understand you correctly, the client won't know the username/password. But how will they be handled on the back-end, then? If I make a call with Postman and specify my credentials in the body of the post (as required by the docs), where do I catch them and evaluate towards my user DB? This part is black magic to me. What do I need to change in my client to achieve it? (I've seen all the examples but get no wiser.)

Comment: That is the hard part. Because it is a flow that needs to be simulated. I've seen a tutorial somewhere online, but I didn't finish it because it was too many steps. I chose the easy way: define a token variable, login yourself on a secured page that shows the access token and copy/paste the token into the variable.

Comment: The client doesn't know the credentials. It can only use the access token. No matter how the access token is obtained in Postman, the client sends it along with the request in the authorization header: 'Bearer <access_token>'. For automated login check [this](https://medium.com/all-technology-feeds/testing-your-asp-net-core-webapi-secured-with-identityserver4-in-postman-97eee976aa16). It references an [example](https://github.com/jorgecotillo/aspnet_core_identity_server_4_postman) that contains a WebApi and IdentityServer4 Quickstart— use username: alice and password: password.

Comment: In IdentityServer there is a login page. That's where the the user logs in and the UserManager accesses the database. After succesful login the user is routed back to the client as configured. For access tokens there are endpoints that can be used. Those calls will not reach any controller. It is possible to validate an access token using introspection. But not required. The JWT stands alone, please read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157049/after-logout-when-validating-access-token-in-introspection-endpoint-is-returning/48159217#48159217) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The client is only allowed to use Implicit Flow to acquire token for accessing the resource which protected by Identity Server :

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
```

But your client is using the [Resource Owner Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) :

> > This grant type is suitable for clients capable of obtaining the
> > resource owner's credentials (username and password, typically using
> > an interactive form).  It is also used to migrate existing clients
> > using direct authentication schemes such as HTTP Basic or Digest
> > authentication to OAuth by converting the stored credentials to an
> > access token.

If you are using SPA application , you should use Implicit Flow to obtain tokens without exposing end user credentials to a third party.

Generally , you have three apps : client app , identity server(with user db)  and api . When using Implicit Flow :

1. Client will redirect user to identity server app, identity server provides UI to let user enter their credentials .
2. After user enter their credential , identity server will validate the credential in DB/configuration file . Of course you can also config the external login in identity server .
3. After validate the credentials , identity server will issue ID Token and access token(if scope includes API resource) back to your client app ,according to the callback url in client's OpenID Connect configuration .
4. Client app will validate and decode the ID token and sign-in user . You can use SDK or directly handle the process manually .
5. If you get the acess token , you can keep the access token in session cache , it can be used to access the protected resource until it is expires .

Comment: What makes you say that I'm using the resource owner flow? I do have *..., AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true, ...*. What am I missing?

Comment: Also, I just realized an issue with #1 there. If it's the identity server that provides UI to enter the credentials, how does it rhyme with different SPAs (totally different web apps that I have no control over to go redirect there? The styles of the different apps may vary. The GUI can't support them all, can it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten , in client you are [requesting a token using the password Grant Type](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html#requesting-a-token-using-the-password-grant-type) ,  you can use fiddler to trace the request , the grant_type should be `password ` , that is why your error occurs .because in identity server you config the client should be allowed to use Implicit flow .

Comment: @KonradViltersten . Different clients should register different callback url in identity server , after identity server validate the credential , it will redirect back to the client according to the callback url . If you trace the token request , you will find callback url is included as query string : https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowSteps